# Using Images API, just the original image gets rotated not the scaled images

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine

I am using Images Api in Java to rotate an image in a server using the [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/images/) provided by Google Cloud.

After I rotate an image, I obtain the public serving url. In order to show different scales, I can change the image url "s" term. s0 refers to the original image. The original image is shown rotated which works as expected. However, when I use the scaled down version of the url like s1000, it still shows me the un-rotated version. Why it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach that did work perfectly in my case was using "r" notation in the serving url of an image.

You can use different "r" notations in a url such as r90, r180, and r270. Make sure not to add r0 or r360 to image serving url, it will throw an error.

You can also resize an image using "s" notation. E.X. s150 will resize the image into the maximum size of 150px.